# Are psychological phenomenon real?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

The symptoms that characterizes one as having a particular psychological phenomenon relies on a subjective analysis of a set of variables, e.g., imposter syndrome, it is not clear what constitutes "an inability to realistically assess your competence and skills" since each person has different frameworks for analyzing their orientation which is influenced by their perception of the world. Contrary to empirical data to determine the existience of a particular disease, psychological phenomena rely on subjectivism. As such, are psychological phenomenon real in the sense that they can't be measured scientifically?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. On the subject of pseudoscience within Psychology, this has [extensively been discussed in meta](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2248). To fully evaluate the existence of each and every "psychological phenomena" to use your words, an answer would be able to fill volumes of books. What psychological phenomena would you like to concentrate on for this question? If it is imposter syndrome, please [edit] your question to narrow the field of research. You can ask about the reality of others in separate questions.

Comment: There is a much better formulation of this question [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9610/7001) that this could be considered a duplicate of.